# HTML table - get content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to extract the content of a HTML table. The table is built up like timetable. On top of the table there is a caption for each column and left at the beginning of each row a number.

I want to read out the content of each cell and link it to the corresponding caption and number.

Here is a fiddle of the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ySbv/4/

I have added a debug part to show the problem. If you click on the bold cell, you get the right number but the false caption.
I read out the caption with the following code:

```
pos = $this.index() + 1,
name = $this.parent().siblings().first().children(':nth-child(' + pos + ')')
```

The table is built up very unhandy. So  I have some problem to get the right index.

Attached a picture of the table structure.
[image: Each color is a tr tag]

Comment: First, the fiddle is good but you should also post the relevant code here. Now the problem: You use `table` as your selector to listen for click events but this will also allow the nested tables to respond (incorrectly) in the same way. Any chance of modifying the html table yourself?

Comment: I have modified the selector. I think "td[rowspan]" should do it. So only the overlying container of the nested table respond to the click event. Unfortunately I am not able to modify the table, because it is the output of a program. http://jsfiddle.net/5ySbv/6/

Comment: Now `.children(':nth-child(' + pos + ')').text()` makes the wrong assumption in certain cases.

Comment: This is going to be difficult and error-prone without using ids, data attributes, or classes to identify what you're clicking on the table.

Comment: You was right. I end up in doing something like iterate in the document ready block through the table and add a data-info attribute for each cell. http://jsfiddle.net/5ySbv/7/